# What am I doing wrong with this contour integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Find $\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z$, where $\gamma$ is the unit circle.

Let $z=x(t) + y(t)$ for $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

Then $x(t) = \cos(t)$ and $y(t) = i\sin(t)$

And $\mathrm{d}z = [i\cos(t) - \sin(t)]\mathrm{d}t$

So $$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z = \int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{[i\cos(t) - \sin(t)]\mathrm{d}t}{\cos(t) + i\sin(t)} = \frac{-1}{i}\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{[\cos(t) + i\sin(t)]\mathrm{d}t}{\cos(t) + i\sin(t)} = \frac{-2\pi}{i}$$

Comment: $-\frac{2\pi}{i}=2\pi i$, so that's right.

Comment: Oh my gosh I'm dumb. Lol

Comment: You could also just directly parameterize the contour with $z=e^{i\theta}$ and the differential cancels with the denominator.

Comment: But, wouldn't you first need to verify that $e^{i\theta}$ is complex differentiable?

Comment: If you're not allowed to assume that $e^{i\theta}$ is not complex differentiable, then I would think you would need to prove it's differentiable first before parameterizing. And one way is to show the Cauchy-Riemann Equations are satisfied. But I would think your teacher would allow you to assume that because it's well known that $e^z$ is differentiable everywhere in the complex plane.

Comment: I don't have a teacher, just trying to teach myself some fun maths, but thank you for the insight.

Comment: @BastionBanner I see. Then if you want, you can go ahead and prove $e^z$ is complex-differentiable everywhere. Regardless if you want to do it or not, your original answer won't be wrong. Sometimes whenever I do some math for fun, I just assume a lot of complicated proofs are true because they're beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Residue theorem and get the result directly. We have that

$\oint_{\gamma}^{}\dfrac{1}{z}dz=2\pi\,i\,Res(f,0)=2\pi\,i\,.1=2\pi\,i$

Answer (score 1):

By using Cauchy's Integral Formula;

Let $\gamma=C$ !

Let f(z) be analytic in a simply connected domain D.Then for any point $z_{0}$ in D and any simple closed path C in D that encloses $z_{0}$, $$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})$$
Since C is the unit circle, |z|=1!
Also, f(z)=1, and the critical point we need to analyze is $z=0$!
It’s evident that $|z|=|0|=0<1$
So $z_{0}=0$ is an interior point!

As a result, $$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi if(z_{0})=2πi(1)=2πi$$